# How to integrate this double integral? It is somehow like the gamma distribution

Tags: calculus, probability-distributions

$$\int_a^b\int_c^d \frac{\beta^\alpha}{\Gamma(\alpha)}(Y-X)^{\alpha-1}e^{-\beta(Y-X)}dYdX $$

Comment: I have no clue what those crazy functions are, but they are constant so we can pull them out of the integral. We have (y-x)^(a-1)e^(-b(y-x)). a standard integration by parts grind should give you the inner integral (and don't forget to evaluate limits)

Comment: Integrating by parts you might get the incomplete Gamma function

Answer (score 0):

The problem looks, at least to me, very complex.

Considering $$F=(Y-X)^{\alpha -1} \,e^{-\beta  (X-Y)}$$ $$G=\int_c^d F \,dY=(c-X)^{\alpha } (\beta  (X-c))^{-\alpha } (\Gamma (\alpha ,(X-c) \beta )-\Gamma
   (\alpha ))+(d-X)^{\alpha } (\beta  (X-d))^{-\alpha } (\Gamma (\alpha )-\Gamma
   (\alpha ,(X-d) \beta ))$$ provided that $\Im\left(\frac{c-X}{c-d}\right)\neq 0\lor \Re\left(\frac{c-X}{c-d}\right)\geq 1\lor
   \Re\left(\frac{c-X}{c-d}\right)\leq 0$ and I do not see how to compute $$H=\int_a^b G \,dX$$ because of the incomplete Gamma function terms.

May be, the last integral could require numerical integration.